# After 10 minutes File watcher start in c#

Tags: c#

I'm craeting FileWatcher in c# and all operation save in database but I want every after 10 minute filewatcher started and insert record into databse so how i do ?

Comment: show your code snippet,.

Comment: Question in English read, how I do?

Answer (score 0):

you can use dispatcher to execute the code on each 10 minutes
example

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
dispatcherTimer.Tick += timer_Tick;

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           //your save db code
}
```

Add reference of System.Windows.Threading dll for DispatcherTimer